# How to disable highlighting ( select ) text in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css rule to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

How to disable highlighting ( select ) text in DIV ?

```
<div id="hello">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

you may wanna look at [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) it may help.